# How to use one Reactjs project as a dependency in another reactjs project

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, npm-link

I have two react.js projects one is major project other is minor , both I have created using `create-react-app`. Now I want to use minor project as a local dependency in my other project without creating npm package.Both projects are in single repo

Comment: Depending on your situation, if each project is in a different repo, you could make a shell script to clone the repo of the minor project into a desired destination in the major project, allowing the code of the minor project to be kept up-to-date more easily than if you copy-pasted the code for each project.